# adding backslash to symbols in python while using the regex library

Tags: python, regex, string, list

So I need to selectively add backslashes to characters that already have pre-defined meaning (such as + and *)in the re library in python.

Say that I am give an array

```
arr = ["five", "+", "two", "*", "zero", "=", "five"]
```

are there any functions within re (or python ) that will allow me to add a \ to "+" and " * ", so it will look like

```
arr = ["five", "\+", "two", "\*", "zero", "=", "five"] ?
```

I can technically do exhausive search and coompare each element within arr to one of the symbols and add \ accordingly, but that is far from ideal. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to escape ?? Non-alphanum, regex meta characters .. ?

Comment: Explain `pre-defined meaning`. For those who read this in the future, that should be clarified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) with either [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) or a list comprehension:

```
>>> import re
>>> arr = ["five", "+", "two", "*", "zero", "=", "five"]
>>> map(re.escape, arr)
['five', '\\+', 'two', '\\*', 'zero', '\\=', 'five']
>>> [re.escape(x) for x in arr]
['five', '\\+', 'two', '\\*', 'zero', '\\=', 'five']
```

Comment: oh wow this is amazing. Thanks for the fast reply! will choose as best answer in a few minutes